# How can i make java tell me the current time in seconds?

Tags: java

Hello i'm new to java and i'm trying to figure out how to use modulus to transform the current time in to seconds. this is what i have so far but i don't know where to go from here.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class firstprogram{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");


        System.out.println( sdf.format(cal.getTime()) );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be one of many possible ways:

**Output** *This is time in seconds*

```
22525
```

**Code**

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 3600 + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) * 60 + calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this works great, can you explain your import statement?

Comment: @MGG as you can see I've used object of `Calendar` class. It is from `java.util.Calendar` package. In order to use it, I've to import this package. You can read more about it from the official documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: oh so the pakage "*" contains the calendar?

Comment: @MGG the class `Calendar` is part of the package `java.util`. The `*` means import all classes out of the given package. Instead of `import java.util.*;` you could also use `import java.util.Calendar;`

Comment: as Maximilian said, `*` means `import everything from `java.util` package. You can also use `import java.util.Calendar`

Answer (score 1):

You can use LocalTime also for this:

```
long secondsOfDay = LocalTime.now().toSecondOfDay();
System.out.println(secondsOfDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

use only "ss"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ss");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
}
```

Comment: if i do this it will only give me 55

Comment: but you said you want current time in seconds...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
long seconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
long seconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(time, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: it gives me an error when i compile

Comment: I don't see any issues with using TimeUnit. What is the compilation error that you get?